# Check if grunt is running in verbose mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

How can I know if grunt is running in verbose mode? Where is this configuration stored?

I'm writing a grunt plugin for a library that already implements the concept of verbose. As I'm not planning to put grunt as a dependency, the library won't have access to something like: `grunt.verbose` from the **[grunt.log](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log)** api. The communication is mostly based on events.

I checked the **[source code](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-legacy-log/blob/master/index.js)** of the log lib, but I was not able to find out how it is available on the `grunt.registerMultiTask` level.

Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy as `grunt.option('verbose')`.